# Insert if Not Exists Else Update Without DUPLICATE KEY or Stored Procedure Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to Insert if Not Exists Else Update With Query in Mysql But Faild.
What i found so far is.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE `branch_id` = 1) 
   THEN 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE `subject` SET (`name` ='KHAN') 
            WHERE `branch_id` = 1
        END        
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO `subject` (`name`,`branch_id`) 
            VALUES('AMAAN', 1) 
        END 
END IF
```

What i Got is

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE `branch_id` = 1)
```

Comment: This form of `IF` only works inside a stored procedure. Could you do this as an "upsert", as in `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try multiple statements from your client program? First do the `update` and then if [`ROW_COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) or equivalent is 0, then do the insert. Of course [`insert on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is simpler.